# How use <p:calendar> correctly?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I'm trying to do a `search` method, for that I use two dates, `checkin` and `checkout`.
I'm starting to use `primefaces` some days ago.

So at `search.xthml` I have:

```
<h:form id="search_form" styleClass="searchform">
  ..
      <p:calendar id="checkin" beforeShowDay="false" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" readonly="true" readonlyInput="true" effect="drop" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" locale="pt" mindate="#{systemC.today}" value="#{systemC.checkin}"> 
        <p:watermark for="checkin" value="Check-in"  />  
      </p:calendar>

      <p:calendar id="checkout" beforeShowDay="false" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" readonly="true" readonlyInput="true" effect="drop" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" locale="pt" mindate="#{systemC.today}" value="#{systemC.checkout}"> 
        <p:watermark for="checkout" value="Check-out"  />  
      </p:calendar>
  ..
</h:form>
```

At my bean, `SystemControl` I have:

```
@ManagedBean(name="systemC")
@SessionScoped
public class SystemControl  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8454359216475311220L;

    private Message message;

    private String search;
    private Date checkin;
    private Date checkout;
    private Integer guests;

    private Date today;

    public String doSearch(){
        System.out.println(search + " " + checkin + " " + checkout + " " +guests);
        return null;
    }
    ..
```

The problem is that, everytime I call the method `doSearch`, both, `checkin` and `checkout` are `null`.
I already look into `primefaces` showcase but still look right what I'm doing here to me.

What I'm missing here ? Any idea ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Just to make sure, are `checkin` and `checkout` fields from `java.util.Date` class type? Also, are you sure the `doSearch` method is invoked in an `UICommand` that belongs to the same form when those `<p:calendar>` components are set?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, Yes Luiggi.

Comment: Where are you calling `doSearch`? Please post the related XHTML-part.

Comment: My view: http://pastebin.com/7cXwzZ83 and my bean: http://pastebin.com/zcFNRFuL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have set `readonly=true`, this will prevent `checkin` and `checkout` from being changed by the `p:calendar`. The primefaces documentation says the following about the `readonly` attriubute:

> Flag indicating that this component will prevent changes by the user.

Comment: you were right man, thank you! I get myself confuse between `reandOnly` and `readonlyInpu`, thank you!